# PCF project No loaders are configured to handle this file CSS

Tags: reactjs, webpack, loader

I npm installed a React timeline library:
https://github.com/veysiyildiz/vertical-timeline-component-for-react#readme

```
npm i vertical-timeline-component-for-react
```

When I use the Timeline example:

```
import { Timeline, TimelineItem }  from 'vertical-timeline-component-for-react';

<Timeline lineColor={'#ddd'}>
  <TimelineItem
    key="001"
    dateText="11/2010 – Present"
    style={{ color: '#e86971' }}
  >
...
```

And then I npm run build.  I get an error:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/vertical-timeline-component-for-react/dist/TimelineItem.css 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> .body-container {
|   position: relative;
|   margin-left: 30px;
```

This is my webpack.config.cs file:

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname, './CaseJourney/CaseJourneyControl/Pages/CaseJourneyDisplayPage.tsx'),
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'output'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', ".tsx", ".ts", ".js"]
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader'
                },
                exclude: /node_modules/
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/, use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"] 
            },
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: "ts-loader",
                        options: {
                            configFile: tsconfigName,
                            transpileOnly: true,
                        },
                    },
                ],
                exclude: /node_modules/,
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: "./public/index.html",
            filename: "./index.html"
         })
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am creating a PCF project.
In my package.json, I have:

```
  "scripts": {
    "build": "pcf-scripts build",
    "clean": "pcf-scripts clean",
    "rebuild": "pcf-scripts rebuild",
    "start": "pcf-scripts start",
    "refreshTypes": "pcf-scripts refreshTypes"
  },
```

The build points to pcf-scripts build.

Thus, I searched how to add css loader to pcf and found this answer:
https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Apps-Pro-Dev-ISV/Extending-the-pcf-scripts-webpack/td-p/383173

Thus, I went to node_modules  --> pcf-scripts --> webpackConfig.js
Then I added this to the rules:

```
     {
          test: /\.css$/,
          use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
     }
```

- Make sure you have npm install --save-dev style-loader css-loader

I npm run build again and it works!